# Sum of elements of matrix that are under the back diagonal

Tags: c++

I have a rectangle-shaped matrix:

```
int arr[3][4] = {1,2,3,4,
                 5,6,7,8,
                 9,1,2,3};
```

And i need to find the sum of elements that are under the back diagonal like this:

```
1, 2, -, 4,|
5, - ,7 ,8,|- these
-, 1, 2, 3 |
   ---------
```

I have the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {

        for (int j = 4; j > 0; j--) {

            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
```

But it does not work correctly.

Will be thankful for any answer.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question and explain the meaning of "does not work correctly"

Answer (score 4):

Replace the second line with

```
for (int j = 3 - i; j < 4; j++) {
```

(And you need to set `sum = 0` before you start.)

Comment: Thaks Bro, it's helped. Wish You all the best.