# How to move negative elements of marix's back diagonal forward

Tags: c++

I have a rectangle-shaped matrix:

```
int arr[3][4] = {1,2,-3,4,
                 5,-6,7,8,
                 9,1,2,3};
```

And I need to move negative items forward along the back diagonal

```
         1, 2, -, 4,
         5, - ,7 ,8,
Diagonal:-, 1, 2, 3
```

like this:

```
int arr[3][4] =  {1,2,9,4,
                 5,-3,7,8,
                 -6,1,2,3};
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Ask yourself: suppose you would have temporary variables to store stuff in, would you be able to devise a programming sequence (using read & write statements on individual array elements) to swap them around?

Comment: It's remarkable that two new users are asking such similar stuff: [SO: Sum of elements of matrix that are under the back diagonal [closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65216435/7478597).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.

- You have 3 rows and 4 columns.
- Loop over the rows

  - Loop over the columns in the current row

    - Is the value in the current `[row][column]` less than `0`? If so, swap the value with the value in `[row+1][column-1]`.

Note: `row+1` and `column-1` may be out of bounds so you need to add logic for wrapping when reaching the boundaries of your array.